# Как называют детенышей куропатки? Какова этимология слова "куропатка"?

Tags: этимология

Как называют детенышей куропатки, куроптенцы?

Answer (score 4):

[**куропа́тка**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6472.htm)
диал. ку́ропоть. род. п. -птя, с.-в.-р. (Подв.); куропа́тва, вост.-русск.; куропта́ха, сиб.; куропя́, тверск., псковск.; куро́хта, южн.; укр. куропа́тва, блр. куропа́тва, др.-русск. мн. куропоти, Домостр. Заб. 150 (из *куропъть). др.-чеш. kuroptva, чеш. kuroptev, в.-луж. kurotwa. Праслав. *kurоръtу. род. *-ръtъvе.

Из **кур** и **пти́ца (*ръtа)**; см. Бернекер 1, 648 и сл.; Мi. ЕW 149; Желтов, ФЗ, 1876, вып. 4, стр. 35; Булаховский, ОЛЯ 7, 115. Последний предполагает без особой надобности древний вариант *kurораtьkа, ср. болг. па́тка, сербохорв. па̏тка "утка". Окончание -атка скорее по аналогии коса́тка и под. (см. Бернекер, там же; Преобр. I, 418). Из первонач. -пт- произошло -т- и -хт-; ср. куро́хта (XVIII в.), откуда курохтан, курухтан; см. Соболевский, РФВ 64, 137. Можно также иметь в виду возможность ономатопоэтического образования *kuro-; ср. голл. kurhoen "куропатка", а также kurren, англ. churring "шум улетающих куропаток" (Бернекер, там же).

Самец куропатки. Орнитологи самца называют **петух**, охотники — *куропач*. Среди местных названий встречаются названия *барабанщик, питун.*

Куропатка — существуют множество местных названий: ***курочка***, куропать, белый тетерев, таловка, ольховка, березовка.

Птенец (птенцы) куропатки — так рекомендуют словари.
Орнитологи, охотники и фермеры называют птенцов куропатки **цыплятами**.

***Каменная куропатка*** обитает по склонам Кавказских гор... Самки несут от восьми до шестнадцати яиц и садятся **высиживать цыплят** (В. В. Бутромеев. Настольная книга охотника).

[**Куро**образные птицы (**куриные**, *Galliformes*)](http://www.ebirds.ru/galliformes/index.htm)

Comment: В подтверждение и в качестве дополнения. По словарю Кузнецова "курицей" может быть не только самка петуха, но и НЕКОТОРЫХ других куриных. Куриные - это отряд. Следовательно, курицей могут быть названые самки различных видов. Из того же словаря Кузнецова: цыплёнок - птенец курицы или др. птицы отряда куриных. И там же пример: цыплёнок фазана. Т.о. цыплёнок куропатки - вполне возможный вариант.